# Proper way of handling listener callbacks that happen on background threads

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, listener, android-runonuithread

In Android using Java, when using a listener callback method that **can be called from multiple threads** according to the documentation, is there any harm in forcing it to run on the main thread by surrounding the method body with `runOnUiThread` like this:

```
@Override
public void onSomeBackgroundTaskCameToAnEndDueToReasonNumber21(final int taskID) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        // put all code here 
    }
}
```

in order to prevent accidentally "touching views" from a background thread in subsequent chains of method calls?

When the Android developers choose to make one of these callback fire on a background thread, what is the reason?

An example of such a class is `UtteranceProgressListener` used on TextToSpeech objects.

Comment: Good question but interesting to see that no answer yet. I think if you have to "touch view" then it should be safely call (runOnUi or whatever preferred) otherwise it should not be a concern. 
The reason I can think of is that the TTS engine is a global, more than one process could be access it or even same process could be calling speak simultaneously so going for background thread is a optimal solution I believe.